# how to restore RST packets sending

Tags: tcp

I used the following rule to drop RST packet

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP
```

now I want to restore RST packet sending, how to do it?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete the rule and things will go back to normal:

```
iptables -D OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST -j DROP
```